# How to get multiple columns by using `Roo` gem in one-line

Tags: ruby, excel, roo

I want to get second to fourth column of a Excel file by using `Roo::Excel` class.

```
columns = []
columns << Roo::Excel.new("foo.xls").column(2)
columns << Roo::Excel.new("foo.xls").column(3)
columns << Roo::Excel.new("foo.xls").column(4)
```

I'm writing code redundantly because `Roo::Excel.new("foo.xls")` itself doesn't return a value even if I wait per minutes, but if I chain the method `column()` then it returns a `Array` instantly.

Is there a DRY way to write the code above?

This is the Excel file I'm trying to read.

http://www.tse.or.jp/listing/kessan/b7gje600000057pv-att/kessan10_1121.xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this [**Ruby's range**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html) ?

```
columns = []
(2..4).each do |r|
 columns << Roo::Excel.new("foo.xls").column(r)
end
```